# Selecting from List<Object> by List<int>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a `List<Record>` and a `List<int>`

I'm trying to select a new `List<Object>` by selecting records from the original list by a `List<int>`

```
List<Record> Records = ...
List<int> RecordIds = new List<int> { 2,4,10 }
```

Here are a couple failing attempts at the syntax

```
List<Record> filteredRecords = Records.Where(p => p.RecordId.Any(z => RecordIds.Contains(z))).ToList();
List<Record> filteredRecords = Records.Where(p => p.Any(z => p.RecordId.Contains(RecordIds))).ToList();
List<Record> filteredRecords = Records.Any(p => p.RecordId.Equals(RecordIds)).ToList();
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the exact syntax to achieve what I want. I know I can achieve this using other various methods, but I'm  trying to figure out the solution using the linq lamba syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Record has a `RecordId: int` field:

```
var filtered = Records.Where(p => RecordIds.Contains(p.RecordId)).ToList();
```

From the original list of records, you take those that have a RecordId that appears in RecordIds list.

Comment: Thanks! The syntax is deceivingly simple. This achieved exactly what I was looking for.